# how do I store the max value of a column as a variable and then use it for calculations in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, max

Here's the code that I am using.

```
  Select max(heart_rate) as Max_heart, Count(*) from exercise_logs 
  where heart_rate between (0.5*Max_heart) and (0.9*Max_heart);
```

I am new with SQL, but I think this would have been easy with something like R. Anyways, since I need to get this done in SQL, any suggestions on how do I do this?

My data looks like this

```
  type            minutes calories heart_rate
  biking          30      100      110
  biking          10       30      105
  dancing         15      200      120
  dancing         15      165      120
  tree climbing   30       70       90
  tree climbing   25       72       80
  rowing          30       70       90
  hiking          60       80       85
```

Comment: What's the desired output should be?

Comment: I suspect that you're making this more complex than it needs to be. Can you describe your problem more thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`User-Defined Variables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-user-variables.html). It should be like

```
  declare var1, var2 INT;

  Select var1 = max(heart_rate), var2 = Count(*) 
  from exercise_logs 
  where heart_rate between (0.5*Max_heart) and (0.9*Max_heart);

  select var1 + var2 as Data;
```

Comment: I dont' think he is asking how to assign result to a variable. I think he wants to find an overall max heart rate and then find activities which result in heart rate of between 50% and 90% of the max rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- Finds maximum heart rate from all activities
SET @Max_heart := ( SELECT  max(heart_rate) FROM exercise_logs );

-- Selects activities that generate between 50% and 90% of the maximum heart rate
Select *
FROM exercise_logs
where heart_rate between (0.5* @Max_heart) and (0.9*@Max_heart);
```